# Fourier transforms for second order pdes

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the equations
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
subject to:
$$u(x,0)=f(x),\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0$$
I started off by taking the fourier transform to get:
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}+\omega^2c^2y=0$$
where $y=y(\omega,t)$ which i separated to $y=W(\omega)T(t)$ then substitued in to get:
$$T''W+\omega^2c^2WT=0\Rightarrow T''+\omega^2c^2T=0$$
which gave the solution:
$$T=A\cos(\omega ct)+B\sin(\omega ct)$$
however I am not sure how to proceed from here in terms of getting back to W then finding $u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange to separate variables the way you have. Since the equation only has derivatives in $t$, you can just solve it like an ODE and let all coefficients depend on $\omega$ since that variable is along for the ride. As is, your $T$ equation has dependence on the variable $\omega$, so the variables aren't really separated and you've introduced an extra degree of freedom. That being said, you have $$y(\omega,t) = A(\omega)\cos(c\omega t) + B(\omega) \sin(c\omega t).$$ You need to get rid of the constants using the initial conditions. The conditions on $u$ transform predictably: $$y(\omega,0) = \hat f(\omega), \,\,\,\,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(\omega,0) = 0.$$ Thus \begin{align*}
A(\omega) &= \hat f(\omega), \\
c\omega B(\omega) &= 0.
\end{align*} The second equation obviously gives $B = 0$. The first gives $A(\omega) = \hat f(\omega).$ Thus $$y(\omega,t) = \hat f(\omega) \cos(c\omega t). $$ Now invert. Remember that the Fourier transform of a convolution gives a product of transforms, and thus the inverse transform of the product should give a convolution. Also, depending on your normalization, the inverse transform of the cosine should be some constant multiple of the sum of two Dirac delta functions.

You can always check your answer against the known answer given by d'Alembert's formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I think I overlooked that sorry

Comment: No problem :) I edited my answer to change function names to be a bit more natural. But all the content is the same. You were well on our way to the correct answer.